# Select max(Data)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
id  cod_pr      Date        nr
-------------------------------
1     22     12.10.2012     2
2     25     12.10.2012     3
3     22     12.11.2012     5
4     25     12.11.2012     2
5     22     12.12.2012     4
6     23     12.10.2012     3
```

How kan I select only max Date from each cod_pr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all columns, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT id,cod_pr,Date,nr,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cod_pr ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RN
   FROM dbo.Table
)
SELECT id,cod_pr,Date,nr, FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Otherwise you can simply use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT cod_pr, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY cod_pr
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cod_pr,MAX(Date) from Table
group by cod_pr
```